# Making static routes persist after a reboot

Tags: networking, centos, routing

I have two VLANs (default vlan and vlan 5 for voip). I have 2 interfaces, one for each VLAN.

My route table looks like this right now:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.5.0     192.168.5.1     255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 eth1.5
192.168.4.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 eth0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1016   0        0 eth1.5
default         192.168.4.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

What I want to do is have `192.168.5.0` destination route through the interface without routing through the gateway (much like the 192.168.4.0 destination).

How can I do this permanently in CentOS? I can easily do it with `route del/add` commands:

```
route del -net 192.168.5.0 gw 192.168.5.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 dev eth1.5
route add -net 192.168.5.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 dev eth1.5
```

But how do I do it by changing the `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1.5` file so that it withstands a reboot?

My `ifcfg-eth1.5` file looks like this now:

```
DEVICE=eth1.5
TYPE=Ethernet
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=yes
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
HWADDR=52:54:00:7c:5f:7c
IPV6INIT=no
NAME="System eth1 on VLAN 5"
VLAN=yes
USERCTL=no
```

I've tried setting `GATEWAY=0.0.0.0`. I've tried setting `PEERROUTES=yes`. `DEFROUTE` used to be no, but didn't make a difference. I've set the default `GATEWAY=192.168.4.1` in the `/etc/sysconfig/network` file.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you already [looked into route-eth1.5](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.2/Deployment_Guide/s1-networkscripts-static-routes.html) Worse comes to worse you should be able to just add the `route add` command to `/etc/rc.local` which gets executed on boot.

Comment: Also, YMMV but you you're doing static routes, I probably wouldn't be using `NetworkManager` since I've seen it cause stability issues in server setups.

Comment: Thanks. I looked into route files--- if I specify `192.168.5.0/24 dev eth1.5` it complains that the gateway is already set and the end result is the same. I've disabled dhcp for now on this interface and have set a static IP on the machine (before static was defined by the dhcp server). End result is gateway isn't being set-- so the DHCP server would have been setting the gateway. I wish the sysconfig allowed this to be overridden.